# How the write(), read() and getvalue() methods of Python io.BytesIO work?

Tags: python, bytesio

I'm trying to understand the **write()** and **read()** methods of **io.BytesIO**.
My understanding was that I could use the **io.BytesIO** as I would use a File 
object.

```
import io
in_memory = io.BytesIO(b'hello')
print( in_memory.read() )
```

The above code will return *b'hello'* as expected, but the code below will return an empty string *b''*.

```
import io
in_memory = io.BytesIO(b'hello')
in_memory.write(b' world')
print( in_memory.read() )
```

My questions are:

-What is `io.BytesIO.write(b' world')` doing exactly?

-What is the difference between **io.BytesIO.read()** and **io.BytesIO.getvalue()**?

I assume that the answer is related to **io.BytesIO** being a stream object, but the big picture is not clear to me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The issue is that you are positioned at the end of the stream. Think of the position like a cursor. Once you have written `b' world'`, your cursor is at the end of the stream. When you try to `.read()`, you are reading everything after the position of the cursor - which is nothing, so you get the empty bytestring.

To navigate around the stream you can use the `.seek` method:

```
>>> import io
>>> in_memory = io.BytesIO(b'hello', )
>>> in_memory.write(b' world')
>>> in_memory.seek(0)  # go to the start of the stream
>>> print(in_memory.read())
b' world'
```

Note that, just like a filestream in `write` (`'w'`) mode, the initial bytes `b'hello'` have been overwritten by your writing of `b' world'`.

`.getvalue()` just returns the entire contents of the stream regardless of current position.

Answer (score 14):

this is a memory stream but still a stream. The position is stored, so like any other stream if you try to read after having written, you have to re-position:

```
import io
in_memory = io.BytesIO(b'hello')
in_memory.seek(0,2)   # seek to end, else we overwrite
in_memory.write(b' world')
in_memory.seek(0)    # seek to start
print( in_memory.read() )
```

prints:

```
b'hello world'
```

while `in_memory.getvalue()` doesn't need the final `seek(0)` as it returns the contents of the stream from position 0.

Answer (score 9):

`BytesIO` does behave like a file, only one that you can both read and write. The confusing part, maybe, is that the reading and writing position is the same one. So first you do:

```
in_memory = io.BytesIO(b'hello')
```

This gives you a bytes buffer in `in_memory` with the contents `b'hello'` and with the read/write position at the beginning (before the first `b'h'`). When you do:

```
in_memory.write(b' world')
```

You are effectively overwriting `b'hello'` with `b' world'` (and actually getting one byte further), and now you have the position at the end (after the last `b'd'`). So when you do:

```
print( in_memory.read() )
```

You see nothing because there is nothing to read *after* the current position. You can, however, use [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) to move the position, so if you do

```
import io
in_memory = io.BytesIO(b'hello')
in_memory.write(b' world')
in_memory.seek(0)
print( in_memory.read() )
```

You get:

```
b' world'
```

Note that you do not see the initial `b'hello'` because it was overwritten. If you want to write *after* the initial content, you can first seek to the end:

```
import io
in_memory = io.BytesIO(b'hello')
in_memory.seek(0, 2)
in_memory.write(b' world')
in_memory.seek(0)
print( in_memory.read() )
```

Output:

```
b'hello world'
```

EDIT: About [`getvalue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getvalue), as pointed out by other answers, it gives you the full internal buffer, independently of the current position. This operation is obviously not available for files.