# How to stream data in python without loading it all into memory at once?

Tags: python, io

I am trying to write and read to a stream without loading everything into memory at once. Here's what I would imagine working:

```
import io

stream = io.BytesIO()

def process_stream(stream):
  while True:
    chunk = stream.read(5).decode('utf-8')
    if not chunk:
      return
    yield chunk

# this would be a separate thread, but here we just do it in serial:
for i in range(3):
  stream.write(b'asdf')

for chunk in process_stream(stream):
  print('I read', chunk)
```

But this actually doesn't print out anything.
I can get it working, but only with the following two changes, either of which requires that all the bytes are held in memory at once:

- initializing `stream = io.BytesIO(b'asdf' * 3)` instead of incrementally writing
- using `stream.getvalue()` instead of incrementally reading

I'm quite baffled that incremental writing can only be read by batch reading, and that incremental reading only works for batch writing. How can a get a constant-memory (assuming `process_stream` outpaces writing) solution working?

Comment: https://dask.org/

Answer (score 1):

When you write to the stream using for loop. Your seek ends up in the last position.

```
asdfasdfasdf|
            ^ (Seek)
```

So when you try to read, well there is nothing after the last character, therefore you get nothing when reading the stream. A solution is to reposition the seek to the beginning of the stream so you can read it. For that we can use `stream.seek(0)`

```
|asdfasdfasdf
^ (Seek after calling stream.seek(0))
```

**Code:**

```
import io

stream = io.BytesIO()


def process_stream(stream, chunk_size=5):
    while True:
        chunk = stream.read(chunk_size).decode('utf-8')
        if not chunk:
            return
        yield chunk


# this would be a separate thread, but here we just do it in serial:
for i in range(3):
    stream.write(b'asdf')

stream.seek(0) # Reset the seek so it is at the beginning
for chunk in process_stream(stream):
    print('I read', chunk)
```

**Output:**

```
I read asdfa
I read sdfas
I read df
```

More information: [How the write(), read() and getvalue() methods of Python io.BytesIO work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53485708/how-the-write-read-and-getvalue-methods-of-python-io-bytesio-work)

Comment: This helps, but I'm still looking for a constant-memory solution. It seems that whenever `.write` is called, the cursor is moved to the end of the stream again. For instance, if I write 'a', seek 0, read, write 'b', read, I get ''. And if I seek 0 again after writing 'b', I get 'ab'. I'm looking for a solution where the 2nd read just gives 'b', the remaining unread bytes, and 'a' is freed from memory. Is BytesIO just not the right tool?