# Azure function blob trigger blob paratemer error

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

I am using a blob trigger to read the blob contents, process as a pandas DF and append the blob to the Azure SQL server I am using.

The blob trigger didn't work as expected so I defined all code in the main function as such:

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    file = re.sub(r'^(.*?)\/','',myblob.name)
    if file not in processedfiles:
        stream = BytesIO((myblob.read()))
        stream.seek(0)
```

However I get the following error:

```
Exception: FunctionLoadError: cannot load the BlobFileTrigger function: 
binding myblob has invalid non-type annotation <sqlalchemy.sql.functions._FunctionGenerator object at 0x7faa340f6a00>
```

Can someone help me find the cause of this issue?

The function.json is configured as follows:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
      {
          "name": "myblob",
          "type": "blobTrigger",
          "direction": "in",
          "path": "input/{name}",
          "connection":"StorageConnection"
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The configured `function.json` file is fine.
- If you are getting an empty byte string, so use the `seek(0)` method first then `Read()` from `stream`.
- Make sure that `if` condition is proper on the `processedfiles`, because if it's not found any files in **processedfiles** then only your case will execute.

  **i.e.:-** `stream = BytesIO((myblob.read()))`

**Reference:** [read() and getvalue() methods of Python io.BytesIO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53485819/18935775)

[Azure Functions with Blobtrigger in Python](https://silasstulz.com/azure-function-blob-trigger-python/)

Comment: It seems importing azure.functions as func collides with func from sqlalchemy, i'll rename and try again.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/568041/sqlalchemy-incompatible-with-python-azure-function.html

Comment: @Stijn, try with that name like **az_func** like that and check.

Comment: yes, thanks again! After renaming to az_func the script worked as intended!