# Pushing polar dataframe to redis

Tags: python, redis, python-polars, py-redis

What is the best way to push a polars dataframe to redis ?

Currently I am trying to read the _io.BytesIO buffer returned by write_ipc

```
redis_instance.set("key",df.write_ipc(file = None, compression="lz4").read())
```

This doesn't seem to work as the key in redis is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write_ipc` returns a BytesIO object. As it has just written, the position is at the end of the stream.  `BytesIO.read()` will start reading from the position onwards, which is in your code empty by definition.

You can instead use `getvalue`, which will always read all contents. See also [this Stackoverflow question on BytesIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53485708/how-the-write-read-and-getvalue-methods-of-python-io-bytesio-work) Alternatively, you can reset the position by calling the method `seek(0)` prior to callling `read()`.